# django-oscar validation error: attribute cannot be blank

Tags: django, django-oscar

Im using the latest django-oscar from the master branch.

I've been tryin to understand how to use oscar, please help me with the problem below.

Using the admin page, first, I add the following Product Attribute

```
Product class: Base Card 
Name: Card Type 
Type: Option  
Option Group: 'Card Type' 
Required: checked
```

Then I tried adding a new Product with the product class `Base Card`. Under the `Product Attribute Values` section, I chose `Card Type` for the attribute, but no matter what values I inserted under e.g Value Option, text or Integer, I keep receiving the validation error below. Any idea why?

```
ValidationError at /admin/catalogue/product/add/
[u'cardtype attribute cannot be blank']
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I'm not able to recreate your issue.

Did you definitely add options to your `Card Type` option group?